# Resolved attribute(s) ... missing from

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I will start with a code dump (self-contained minimal but representative example), followed by the output and afterwards will provide the problem statement.

With that out of the way: code dump (pyspark 2.4.8, python 3.6 code):

```py
import sys

import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

local = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = local.sparkContext


print('pyspark version:', pyspark.__version__)
print('python version:', sys.version)


def dump_df(name):
    df = globals()[name]
    print(f'-------------------------------- {name}')
    df.explain()
    df.show()
    print(f'-------------------------------- /{name}')


a = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (0, 'EN', f'English text', 0),
        (0, 'NL', f'Nederlandse tekst', 0),
    ])
    .toDF("id: integer, language: string, value: string, _usecase: integer")
    .alias('translation_table')
)
dump_df('a')

en = a.filter('language = "EN"').alias('en')
dump_df('en')

nl = a.filter('language = "NL"').alias('nl')
dump_df('nl')

lookup = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (0, f'English text', 0),
        (0, f'Nederlandse tekst', 0),
    ])
    .toDF('id: integer, AttributeValue: string, _usecase: integer')
    .withColumn('PlatformValue', F.lit('platvalue'))
    .alias('lookup')
)
dump_df('lookup')

left_usecase = getattr(lookup, '_usecase')
right_usecase = getattr(en, '_usecase')

step1 = (
    lookup.join(
        en,
        [
            left_usecase == right_usecase,

            (col('lookup.id') == col('en.id')) & (col('lookup.AttributeValue') == col('en.value')),
        ],
        'left',
    )
    .drop(right_usecase)
)
dump_df('step1')


left_usecase = getattr(lookup, '_usecase')
right_usecase = getattr(nl, '_usecase')


try:
    step2 = (
        step1.join(
            nl,
            [
                left_usecase == right_usecase,

                (col('lookup.id') == col('nl.id')) & (col('lookup.AttributeValue') == col('nl.value')),
            ],
            'left',
        )
        .drop(right_usecase)
    )
except AnalysisException as ex:
    print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! EXCEPTION')
    print(str(ex).replace('\\n', '\n'))
    print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! /EXCEPTION')
else:
    dump_df('step2')
```

The output:

```
pyspark version: 2.4.8
python version: 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 16 2021, 11:37:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
-------------------------------- a
== Physical Plan ==
Scan ExistingRDD[id#0,language#1,value#2,_usecase#3]
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
| id|language|            value|_usecase|
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  0|      EN|     English text|       0|
|  0|      NL|Nederlandse tekst|       0|
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+

-------------------------------- /a
-------------------------------- en
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(language#1) && (language#1 = EN))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0,language#1,value#2,_usecase#3]
+---+--------+------------+--------+
| id|language|       value|_usecase|
+---+--------+------------+--------+
|  0|      EN|English text|       0|
+---+--------+------------+--------+

-------------------------------- /en
-------------------------------- nl
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(language#1) && (language#1 = NL))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0,language#1,value#2,_usecase#3]
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
| id|language|            value|_usecase|
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  0|      NL|Nederlandse tekst|       0|
+---+--------+-----------------+--------+

-------------------------------- /nl
-------------------------------- lookup
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, platvalue AS PlatformValue#53]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#47,AttributeValue#48,_usecase#49]
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+
| id|   AttributeValue|_usecase|PlatformValue|
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+
|  0|     English text|       0|    platvalue|
|  0|Nederlandse tekst|       0|    platvalue|
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+

-------------------------------- /lookup
-------------------------------- step1
== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, platvalue AS PlatformValue#53, id#0, language#1, value#2]
+- SortMergeJoin [_usecase#49, id#47, AttributeValue#48], [_usecase#3, id#0, value#2], LeftOuter
   :- *(1) Sort [_usecase#49 ASC NULLS FIRST, id#47 ASC NULLS FIRST, AttributeValue#48 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(_usecase#49, id#47, AttributeValue#48, 200)
   :     +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#47,AttributeValue#48,_usecase#49]
   +- *(3) Sort [_usecase#3 ASC NULLS FIRST, id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, value#2 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(_usecase#3, id#0, value#2, 200)
         +- *(2) Filter ((((isnotnull(language#1) && (language#1 = EN)) && isnotnull(_usecase#3)) && isnotnull(id#0)) && isnotnull(value#2))
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0,language#1,value#2,_usecase#3]
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+----+--------+------------+
| id|   AttributeValue|_usecase|PlatformValue|  id|language|       value|
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+----+--------+------------+
|  0|Nederlandse tekst|       0|    platvalue|null|    null|        null|
|  0|     English text|       0|    platvalue|   0|      EN|English text|
+---+-----------------+--------+-------------+----+--------+------------+

-------------------------------- /step1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! EXCEPTION
'Resolved attribute(s) _usecase#3 missing from _usecase#127,id#124,language#125,value#2,id#0,id#47,AttributeValue#48,_usecase#49,language#1,PlatformValue#53,value#126 in operator !Join LeftOuter, ((_usecase#49 = _usecase#3) && ((id#47 = id#124) && (AttributeValue#48 = value#126))). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: _usecase. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
!Join LeftOuter, ((_usecase#49 = _usecase#3) && ((id#47 = id#124) && (AttributeValue#48 = value#126)))
:- Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, PlatformValue#53, id#0, language#1, value#2]
:  +- Join LeftOuter, ((_usecase#49 = _usecase#3) && ((id#47 = id#0) && (AttributeValue#48 = value#2)))
:     :- SubqueryAlias `lookup`
:     :  +- Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, platvalue AS PlatformValue#53]
:     :     +- LogicalRDD [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49], false
:     +- SubqueryAlias `en`
:        +- Filter (language#1 = EN)
:           +- SubqueryAlias `translation_table`
:              +- LogicalRDD [id#0, language#1, value#2, _usecase#3], false
+- SubqueryAlias `nl`
   +- Filter (language#125 = NL)
      +- SubqueryAlias `translation_table`
         +- LogicalRDD [id#124, language#125, value#126, _usecase#127], false
'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! /EXCEPTION
```

The issue is this `Resolved attribute(s) _usecase#3 missing from ...` error.
If you check plan for the `nl` dataframe, the identifier of `_usecase` is 3.
But in the creation of the `step2` dataframe suddenly the identifier I want to join with becomes `_usecase#127` instead (see the exception message and its plan)...
So, of course spark doesn't now (anymore) what `_usecase#3` is.

Very likely this is because I had a previous join with a subset of the same data (language = 'EN')...

Is this a known bug?

What can I do to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have removed `_usecase#3` yourself right after you joined `lookup` with `en`.

`en` contains `_usecase#3`:

```
:     +- SubqueryAlias `en`
:        +- Filter (language#1 = EN)
:           +- SubqueryAlias `translation_table`
:              +- LogicalRDD [id#0, language#1, value#2, _usecase#3], false
```

`lookup` contains `_usecase#49`:

```
:     :- SubqueryAlias `lookup`
:     :  +- Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, platvalue AS PlatformValue#53]
:     :     +- LogicalRDD [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49], falsenone
```

After you join them, you do `.drop(right_usecase)`.

[image]

Since `right_usecase` corresponds to `en`, with this `drop` step you remove `_usecase#3`.

From this point, the joined dataframe has only `_usecase#49`

```
:- Project [id#47, AttributeValue#48, _usecase#49, PlatformValue#53, id#0, language#1, value#2]
```

Then you want to join this with `nl` dataframe. `_usecase#127` "joins the party" together with `nl`.

```
+- SubqueryAlias `nl`
   +- Filter (language#125 = NL)
      +- SubqueryAlias `translation_table`
         +- LogicalRDD [id#124, language#125, value#126, _usecase#127], false
```

So now you have `_usecase#49` and `_usecase#127` on the table, but your join condition also expects to find `_usecase#3`...

```
!Join LeftOuter, ((_usecase#49 = _usecase#3) && ((id#47 = id#124) && (AttributeValue#48 = value#126)))
```

Comment: Hope this helps, as I can't fully test the script, I get a major version error on step 1 show, even with Spark 2.4.8.